# Slice pandas DataFrame where column's value exists in another array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with a large amount of data. In one column are randomly repeating keys. In another array I have a list of of theys keys for which I would like to slice from the `DataFrame` along with the data from the other columns in their row.

**keys**:

```
keys = numpy.array([1,5,7])
```

**data**:

```
 indx   a      b     c   d
    0   5   25.0  42.1  13
    1   2   31.7  13.2   1
    2   9   16.5   0.2   9
    3   7   43.1  11.0  10
    4   1   11.2  31.6  10
    5   5   15.6   2.8  11
    6   7   14.2  19.0   4
```

I would like slice all rows from the `DataFrame` if the value in the column `a` matches a value from `keys`.

**Desired result**:

```
 indx   a      b     c   d
    0   5   25.0  42.1  13
    3   7   43.1  11.0  10
    4   1   11.2  31.6  10
    5   5   15.6   2.8  11
    6   7   14.2  19.0   4
```

Comment: slices aren't conditional, you'll have to apply a filter.

Comment: `df[df.a.isin(keys)]`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `isin`:

```
>>> df[df.a.isin(keys)]
      a     b     c   d
indx                   
0     5  25.0  42.1  13
3     7  43.1  11.0  10
4     1  11.2  31.6  10
5     5  15.6   2.8  11
6     7  14.2  19.0   4

[5 rows x 4 columns]
```

or `query`:

```
>>> df.query("a in @keys")
      a     b     c   d
indx                   
0     5  25.0  42.1  13
3     7  43.1  11.0  10
4     1  11.2  31.6  10
5     5  15.6   2.8  11
6     7  14.2  19.0   4

[5 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: It's helpful to get used to making a boolean array or Series and using that to index into `df` directly or via `.loc`.  That's probably one of the most common ways to operate on frames.  For example, `df[~df.a.isin(keys)]` would give you the complement of this.